# Zend Framework is throwing a strange error in Firefox and IE about the PDO?

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, postgresql, pdo

At work we are using Zend 1.10.7 and were getting a weird error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08P01]: <<Unknown error>>: 7 ERROR:  bind message supplies 0 parameters, but prepared statement "pdo_stmt_00000015" requires 1' in /var/www/ZendFramework-1.10.7/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:

#0 /var/www/ZendFramework-1.10.7/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/ZendFramework-1.10.7/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/ZendFramework-1.10.7/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(468): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/ZendFramework-1.10.7/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query(Object(Zend_Db_Table_Select), Array)
#4 /var/www/ZendFramework-1.10.7/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(1505): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query(Object(Zend_Db_Table_Select))
#5 /var/www/ZendFramework-1.10.7/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(1321): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_fetch(Object(Zend_Db_Table_Select))
#6 /var/w in /var/www/ZendFramework-1.10.7/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 234
```

Has any one ever seen this before? and if so what's the cause? it only does this in Firefox and IE 9. **But chrome is fine, the site works.**

Any thoughts? Too me, and my Google mind its one of my inserts or select statements, but again in chrome it works, selects, inserts and updates information in the database.

we are using PostgreSQL as a database

Comment: Are you sure that your tests in each browser are identical? - What I mean is that you should be looking at the values passed to the query NOT the browser

Comment: Meaning?

All I am doing is going to the site url in each browser and only chrome not spazzing out. Do you know what this issue is?

Answer (score 1):

The PDO query is looking for a bound parameter, with this said there should be no reason why different browsers are giving different results unless the values passed to this query are dynamically generated -

If your query looks like this:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?`

You need to ensure you bind one parameter.

`$stmt->bindParam(1, $idValue);`

If `$idValue` is the result of a function that for some reason returns NULL or the bindParam method call itself is wrapped in a conditional statement that only evaluate true on Christmas day you will have an exception like yours. This is because the value is missing when the statement is executed.

Edit: My guess is that the `Array` value here `PDOStatement->execute(Array)` is empty.